# Order of inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was inspecting Northwind database. There is one View called 'Invoice' fairly complicated.

I tried to change the original sql (pull last inner join up, merge with the other inner join statement).

'Official' code to get invoice: (correct)

```
SELECT *
 FROM           dbo.Shippers        as shipper
 INNER JOIN     dbo.Products        as product
 INNER JOIN     dbo.Employees  as employee
 INNER JOIN     dbo.Customers  as customer
 INNER JOIN     orders         as orders
 ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID 
 ON employee.EmployeeID = orders.EmployeeID 
 INNER JOIN     dbo.[Order Details] 
 ON orders.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID 
 ON product.ProductID = dbo.[Order Details].ProductID 
 ON shipper.ShipperID = orders.ShipVia
```

My first try: (doesn't work)

```
SELECT *
     FROM           dbo.Shippers        as shipper
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Products        as product
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Employees  as employee
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Customers  as customer
     INNER JOIN     orders         as orders
     INNER JOIN     dbo.[Order Details] 
     ON orders.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID 
     ON product.ProductID = dbo.[Order Details].ProductID 
     ON shipper.ShipperID = orders.ShipVia
     ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID 
     ON employee.EmployeeID = orders.EmployeeID
```

My second try (works):

```
select      *
from Orders as orders
    inner join Shippers as ships
        on ships.ShipperID = orders.ShipVia
    inner join [Order Details] as ods
        on ods.OrderID = orders.OrderID 
    inner join Products as products
        on ods.ProductID = products.ProductID
    inner join Customers as customers
        on customers.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
```

Both of them return 2155 lines of record.

Here is a reference for Table Structure:
[image]

My question is why 'my first try' is not right ?
Also, do you think my second try is right ?

Thanks

Comment: 'Official' code works. Still pass the syntax checking. @John Woo

Comment: Incorrect Syntax of INNER JOIN results in error. Check this syntax from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: What's the problem with the first try? Are you getting a syntax error? If so, can you please share it?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "product.ProductID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "shipper.ShipperID" could not be bound. @Mureinik

Comment: @Paresh J   I read through the link. It doesn't shows me syntax for INNER JOIN..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `ON` clause is used to specify the join conditions for the most immediate preceding `JOIN` clause that hasn't yet had an `ON` specified.

So, indenting to show how they're matching up:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM           dbo.Shippers        as shipper
 INNER JOIN     dbo.Products        as product
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Employees  as employee
         INNER JOIN     dbo.Customers  as customer
             INNER JOIN     orders         as orders
                 INNER JOIN     dbo.[Order Details] 
                 ON orders.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID 
             ON product.ProductID = dbo.[Order Details].ProductID
         ON shipper.ShipperID = orders.ShipVia
     ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID 
 ON employee.EmployeeID = orders.EmployeeID
```

And the most deeply nested `JOIN` will be performed first. So, whilst the inner most join seems to be correct (joining `orders` to `Order Details` with an `ON` clause of `orders.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID`), the next one out is incorrect - we're trying to join `customer` to the result of the previous join (or `orders` and `order details`), but with an `ON` clause of `product.ProductID = dbo.[Order Details].ProductID` - and that's wrong because we've not joined to the `product` table yet.

You might try re-arranging them as:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM           dbo.Shippers        as shipper
 INNER JOIN     dbo.Products        as product
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Employees  as employee
         INNER JOIN     dbo.Customers  as customer
             INNER JOIN     orders         as orders
                 INNER JOIN     dbo.[Order Details] 
                 ON orders.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID 
             ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID 
         ON employee.EmployeeID = orders.EmployeeID
     ON product.ProductID = dbo.[Order Details].ProductID
 ON shipper.ShipperID = orders.ShipVia
```

Where now at least each `ON` clause is dealing in terms of table aliases that are in scope for each join.

However, I'd usually recommend (except for complex joins) to follow a pattern of:

```
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.column = b.column
INNER JOIN c
    ON a_or_b.column = c.column
...
```

Where each `ON` clause is kept close to the `JOIN` clause that it's actually specifying the conditions for, much like your second attempt. I can see no reason for trying to get all of the `JOIN`s to occur at the top of the `FROM`.

Comment: @Codefarmer: Damien is absolutely correct. One after the other inner join behaves like nested subquery. As shown in the official code, Inner most join orders is joined with other tables than comes the orderdetails table joins with other tables. And, hence rearrangement is one of factor in INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

in your 1st try, you didn't link Shipper to Order table.

```
SELECT *
     FROM           dbo.Shippers        as shipper
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Products        as product
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Employees  as employee
     INNER JOIN     dbo.Customers  as customer
     INNER JOIN     orders         as orders
     INNER JOIN     dbo.[Order Details] 
     ON orders.OrderID = dbo.[Order Details].OrderID 
     ON product.ProductID = dbo.[Order Details].ProductID 
     ON shipper.ShipperID = orders.ShipVia
     ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID 
     ON employee.EmployeeID = orders.EmployeeID
```

2ndly when you use join, you have to mention the columns of the two table on which the join will be  done.

so when you join x and join y then you have to mention column of x and column of y. otherwise it will be a Cartesian product. when you make a join just immediately you have to mention the column.

in your second query, the ideal practice is link all the associated table 1st. 
you can re-write it like:

```
select      *
from Orders as orders
    inner join Shippers as ships
        on orders.ShipVia= ships.ShipperID  
    inner join Customers as customers
        on orders.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID
    inner join [Order Details] as ods
        on orders.OrderID  = ods.OrderID

    inner join Products as products
        on ods.ProductID = products.ProductID
```